# AngularJS parallel http request and handle redundant data

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, angularjs, http

I am making a single page application using AngularJS and ASP.NET Webforms and I am quite a newbie at it.

I am stuck at a problem and want to know if this is doable or not, and if yes then how? It will be great if anyone of you experts can help.

**Scenario**

I have 3 urls. Each URL will return me a JSON data. Now, I want to show the data on First-Download-First-Show basis ( I do not want to wait for all request to complete as some will take time).

Consider example. We have 3 url which makes 3 requests (requests 1,2,3).

Order of completion of request is 1,3,2.

So it will show results of request 1, then when 3 completes it will update ui for 3's result and finally for 2's result.

Each result data will have an ID, so if request1 is completed and then request 3 is completed, request3's result data will check if data with same ID exists. If it exists,it will update the current data, if not, it will create new data.

I want to know if this is doable and if yes then how?

I am stuck since 3 days and any help will be appreciated.

I tried this first with aspx website but it used to wait till all 3 requests to complete then only show the data.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What request are you using in ajax.Post some code that you tried

Comment: @sriram I tried to call controller normally as shown in http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp

Comment: I used chaining with .then function(). But that doesn't work parallely, it will be dependent on first source to complete then next will be processed. I do not know which request will take long. So I asked how to call them effeciently

Comment: .then function will always wait for the first request to complete. why don't you send all the request independently and check with a common value in all three request which will tell each request whether any other request has completed or not.